# Getting console output of Windows GUI application

Tags: mfc, printf, executable, output-redirect

I'm running a exe file that has cprintf calls in one of its DLLs, the exe is GUI application, I'm looking for a method to get the output of the cprintf calls.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know, what `cprintf` is. If you are referring to the standard `printf` instead, simply call [AllocConsole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole) and you will see the output.

Comment: I don't have access to the code. Its compiled program

Comment: From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/allocconsole): _"If the calling process creates a child process, the child inherits the new console."_

Answer (score 1):

This was solved by loading DLL on runtime that called `AllocConsole()` in `DLLMain`.